# How to properly center a Text widget in a shrinked Container within a Stack

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I want a **container** which **shrinks** to it's **content**. This container should be placed in a **stack**, so that the container has no constraints from outside.

```
    ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 150.0, minHeight: 48.0),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8), border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
        child: SelectableText(
          "Text",
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image]

This code lets the container shrink around my Text, which is what I want.

Now I want to **center the child widget** (Text) in my container. I wrap the Text with a Center widget and it stretches the container up the whole available vertical space, which was obviously not my intention.
The closest I could get is the solution with a column :

```
    ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 150.0, minHeight: 48.0),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8), border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            SelectableText(
              "Node",
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

This centers my text vertically but not horizontally and it doesn't feel like it's the correct way to achiece what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapped in `Center` widget

```
    ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 150.0, minHeight: 48.0),
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          child: SelectableText("Text"),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Comment: This makes my content ignore the minHeight constraint from above.

Comment: @TobiasW I just showed you how to center the widget.

Comment: and I commented before, that this is not the solution since the BoxConstraints stops working with your solution.

Comment: I tested that the `minHeight` constraint works:  https://dartpad.dartlang.org/94476d98f5bb81f4d064c6a23e3ad485

Comment: Either I got a wrong version of the dartpad file or you accidentally rendered the code from my answer instead if your posted solution.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: In the build function you call post2 which is my code from the question and not yours. So the output kinda works yes, but the output from post1 has still no minHeight.